# Create a list of elements 0 to 1 with a specified number of elements

Tags: python, list

How do I use Python to create a list of a specified number of elements that increases from 0 to 1?

To be more clear, I want to generate a list of `3270` elements that increase linearly from 0 to 1. Since I need such a large list, I think it's improbable for me to specify the step.

I tried to use `list(range())`, but that only works for integers.

Answer (score 3):

```
[x / 3270.0 for x in xrange(0, 3271)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

elements = np.linspace(0., 1., 3270)
```